# Appstore - How to delete Prepare for submission tvOS

Tags: ios

We have an iOS app which is ready to upload in the Appstore(Now is in prepare for submission). But unfortunately tvOS application selected as wrongly and it is also prepared for submission now. So we only need iOS application to upload into the app store not tvOS App. Now we couldn’t make Our App to submit for a review without this tvOS app. Kindly please let me know any option to delete the tvOS app from prepare for submission.

Comment: Currently I haven't developed tvOS app to submit for a review. wrongly selected tvOS and prepare for submission. It will be great help if someone who find a way that remove tvOS app from prepare for submission

Comment: Even if you don't delete it, it won't prevent you from submitting the iOS version.

Comment: Me too have a same thought.But When trying to submit review it asks to missing  'Apple TV Privacy Policy' from App Information Tab in the app store account. Once we add some description and submit the app following error showing
'An unexpected error was encountered when submitting for review.If the issue persists please contact us'
This is totally strange for me from Apple.
So that may be the reason of this tvOS prepare submission issue.
If I can delete the tvOS from the prepare submission, there we don't need to fill this option  'Apple TV Privacy Policy'.

Comment: Yes, you need to enter some text into the AppleTV privacy policy text box because that is in the base app metadata screen.  Once you do that you can submit your iOS app for review without needing to submit an tvOS app.

Comment: I did that. But got an error like this. "An unexpected error was encountered when submitting for review.If the issue persists please contact us'"

Comment: Anyway, you have your answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hover over the tvOS App on the left menu, you will get a minus symbol. With a click on this button, you can delete it.

[image: Screenshot of App Store Connect (German)]

**Update:**

Please see the following matrix for restrictions:

[image: Permission / restriction matrix]

Comment: But I could not see minus delete button here. Is this restricted for App manager ? Only admin or Account holder can do this ?

Comment: As far as I know, only the Account Holder and the Admin are able/allowed to do that. I will update my post with the permission matrix from Apple.

Comment: Thank you. Now I could able to delete the tvOS app from prepare for submission.

Comment: Nuh, I'm the account holder and there is no delete button when hovering

Answer (score 5):

This is how I finally solved it: I also could't see the delete button at first when hovering over the tvOS app even with an Admin account. As soon as I created a new iOS version, the delete button would show up on the tvOS app and let me delete it.

Comment: Delete button appeared as you mentioned, but when I delete, "The resource can not be found" error occur.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same message trying to submit an iOS app to App Store. I think they updated iTunes Connect web site na have some issues currently.

Comment: "An unexpected error was encountered when submitting for review.If the issue persists please contact us "

When hit 'submit for review' button, this message showing for me now.